# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in IntelliJ IDE Spark project

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, ojdbc

Hi I am facing the below issue while executing Sparksql Job(to read the Oracle table) in IntellJ IDE.
Issue:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)`

I have already added the ojdbc7.jar file in my project in IntelliJIdea ProjectStructure==>Modules==> Dependencies ==> + ==> Added ojdbc7.jar file.

In build.gradle file i have given the below statement.

"runtime files('libs/ojdbc7.jar')"

After i compiled my project i could see the jar file in libs folder that i have created in my project.

If i execute the Job in IDE I am facing this issue. Can any one please help me on the same.

Comment: how are you executing the Sparksql Job ?

Comment: @Arunakiran, from IDE

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: ` val query = "(SELECT * FROM tablename limit 3) QUERYNAME"
val temp_df = sqlContext.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
        .option("url", "url")
        .option("dbtable", query).load()
      temp_df.show(5)`

Comment: This is the code that I am trying to submit.

Comment: Or I can also give in single statement like below.

Comment: val temp_df = sqlContext.read .format("jdbc") .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") .option("url", "my_Oracle_url") .option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM tablename limit 3)").load()

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your database using spark ?

Comment: @ Arunakiran, Yes

Comment: In Eclipse gradle project i was executing the very similar code to fetch the Oracle table data, and it was working fine. In Eclipse to add the ojdbc7 jar file i have added  it in BuildPath==> ExternalJars and add the jar file. If i submit the Job in EclipseIDE i was able to read the Oracle table data. But not sure in IntellJ IDE gradle project why its not working.

Answer (score 6):

You need to download the driver on Intellij IDE itself and not the project you are working on since it's Intellij that needs the driver, the one in your project you can keep it since your application will need it.
In your IDE, go to **Database** Menu on your right, chose the connection you created to connect to the DB then **Properties**.
At the bottom it should show you a link, **Download Missing Driver**, click on that and you should be able to do your SQL queries using Intellij IDE.